# Prime Implicant in z3

Tags: z3

I look for a solution to find (minimum) prime implicant for a formula in QF_AUBV logic using z3 solver. is it possible to get such a partial prime implicant from z3 solver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but there is no function that will do that job. You may have to use quantifiers (to axiomatize the notion of implicants) and/or repeated SAT queries (to minimize implicants).

Comment: thanks very much for your reply. If I'm right , you mean that I must have an algorithm to find prime implicant.                                                                I read about relevancy propagation in z3 that just essential truth assignments for satisfying formula, propagate to theory solver. can I benefit from this assignments. am I right that these are partial assignment that may be prime implicant for formula or maybe not. if yse, can I extract the propagated assignments to theory solver from formula?

Comment: If you are implementing a theory solver this could perhaps help (start looking at relevant_eh(...) in other theories), otherwise it's probably not worth the (quite considerable) effort. Note that relevancy also propagates for non-Boolean subterms. If you are looking for all (prime or other) implicants, then you will need multiple SAT queries, not just a single one, so it's probably best to implement all of that in an outer layer instead of the inside of the SMT solver.

Comment: thanks very much. you're right. could I please you to more explain about using quantifies to axiomatize  notion of implicants. it's vague for me.

Comment: You can encode primality by stating that ... there \exists a (Boolean) polynomial (or sum of products; or coefficients thereof) that has the property that it implies the original formula, and, additionally, \forall polynomials that are smaller (e.g. less 1-bits, or smaller bit-vector), they do not imply the original formula. (See 'Implicant' in Wikipedia for slightly more formal definitions). Note that adding quantifiers for this sort of purpose will likely result in much higher runtimes and the solver will `give up' and return 'unknown' if it thinks the problem is too hard (or undecidable).

Comment: Thanks so much. In these days, I found an algorithm for computing minimum satisfying assignments(MSA). In this algorithm, instead of finding  MSA, it is preferd to find the complement of this set that is named Maximum universal set(MUS) with a bound & branch algorithm that is implemented by using quantifiers and repeated sat queries.my problem is that this algorithm uses an boolean abstraction , in that two atoms A and (not A) are replaced with different boolean variables. but can I have this boolean abstraction via z3 solver?

Comment: Of course, you can add as many Boolean variables as you like and then add constraints over them, e.g., (=> x (predicate ...)) where x is a new Boolean.